# NGINX renders PHP files when given path, serves index as download without a path

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, nginx-config

My current NGINX & PHP-FPM setup works when given a working filepath like example.com/index.php, but still serves the index.php as a download when visiting example.com without a file.

I've tried adding a location / redirect and try_files, but it still doesn't redirect properly.

I know how it's done using .htaccess files, but I'd like to do this in NGINX to avoid changing every repository.

Here's my current conf file.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` from `location ~ \.php$ {`.

Comment: Removing that and adding `index index.php` as a global parameter fixed it. Thanks